# robot_pose_ekf and AMCL

Tags: navigation, robot-pose-ekf, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I have my own robot that works on odometry and lidar using **AMCL**. Everything works perfectly.
After that, I decided to use **robot_pose_ekf** to improve data. I use the MPU6050 sensor and odometry from wheels data for this. /robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined give me a data.
But I encountered such a problem that I do not know how to connect the robot_pose_ekf package to my the ready system with the AMCL.
I searched the Internet, and did not find the information.
In which files do I need to make changes to connect robot_pose_ekf?

In launch file I wrote.

```
    <node pkg="robot_pose_ekf" type="robot_pose_ekf" name="robot_pose_ekf">
  <param name="output_frame" value="odom_combined"/>
  <param name="base_footprint_frame" value="base_link"/>
  <param name="freq" value="30.0"/>
  <param name="sensor_timeout" value="1.0"/>  
  <param name="odom_used" value="true"/>
  <param name="imu_used" value="true"/>
  <param name="vo_used" value="false"/>
  <param name="publish_tf" value="true"/>
  <remap from="odom" to="odom"/>
  <remap from="imu_data" to="imu_data" />
</node>
```

But navigation does not work. The terminal gets out of error.

```
Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: . canTransform returned after 0.100751 timeout was 0.1
```

Here is fragment of my original tf tree of working system, without robot_pose_ekf.
[Without robot_pose_ekf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_AbvNqvPPw1bC1WeXppbDVFNVE/view?usp=sharing)

With robot_pose_ekf graph is the same exept frame called not "odom" but "odom_combined" and published by robot_pose_ekf.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274501/robot_pose_ekf-and-amcl/) by [Andrey](https://answers.ros.org/users/32433/andrey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-10-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your problem might be that you now have two parents for "base_link" in your tf tree, "odom" and "odom_combined".

robot_pose_ekf has two outputs, the published topic "odom_combined" and the tf transform:

1. The tf transform looks misconfigured in your launch file, you have set output_frame to "odom_combined" which does not exist in your tf tree. Note: output_frame is not the name of the published odometry topic, but the name of your odometry frame, [see rep 105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html#odom). So you should set output_frame to "odom". Since you can have only one publisher for this transform, this implies that you disable your previous publisher of the odom->base_link transform which is "diff_tf" in your tf tree.
2. Finally if you have any node that subscribes to /odom you might want it to subscribe to /robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined instead.

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2017-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrey](https://answers.ros.org/users/32433/andrey/) on 2017-10-31**:
Thank a lot. I'' try it.
Can you tell me if I need only to change the odom_frame_id parameter to connect to the amcl and that's all?
And is there a problem in that, initially, the robot_pose_ekf transfer tf in base_footprint instead of base_linkl? I have remaped it in launch, but is will this work?

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-10-31**:\

1. You better not change the "odom_frame_id" param in amcl, just change it in robot_pose_ekf. 2. You have set "base_footprint_frame" param to "base_link", so I don't see any "base_footprint" frame.

**Comment by [Andrey](https://answers.ros.org/users/32433/andrey/) on 2017-10-31**:
Okay.How i can change "odom_frame_id" in robot_pose_ekf? I wrote *param name="odom_frame_id" value="odom"/* in launching robot_pose_ekf but nothing happens. And if i did remap from="/robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined" to="odom" i have 2 topics with the same name with odom from diff_tf. How i can do this?

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-11-01**:
"odom_frame_id" is amcl parameter, corresponding parameter in robot_pose_ekf is "output_frame".

**Comment by [Andrey](https://answers.ros.org/users/32433/andrey/) on 2017-11-02**:
Okay, thank you I'll try it.